# Read two columns by header from csv file using java 8

Tags: java, lambda, csvreader

I want to read two columns (col5 and col7) from csv file by header.

With below code I can read only one column header (col5). Is there any way to read two columns in the same map itself.

Why I choose map is I need to process data later.

```
public static List<String> getData() throws IOException {
        String titleToSearchFor = "col5";
        Path path = Paths.get("D:/blackduck_sample.txt");

        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

            List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(lines.get(0).split(","));

            int titleIndex = columns.indexOf(titleToSearchFor);

            List<String> values = lines.stream().skip(1).map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))
                    .map(list -> list.get(titleIndex)).filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(s -> s.trim().length() > 0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return values;
        }

        return new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

My sample CSV file

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SnakeYAML:2.1:3,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,TRUE,FALSE,Overdue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:Apache Tomcat:9.0.70:1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <= 90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-bh-registry-svc:Jettison - Json Stax implementation:1.5.3:1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <=90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:Apache Tomcat:9.0.70:2,TRUE,FALSE,Due in >90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:jackson-databind:2.14:1,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:jackson-databind:2.14:1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <= 90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,TRUE,FALSE,Overdue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
```

I tried to search google and stackfoverflow and ended up with either one column or read by index

```
String[] cols = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    System.out.println("Coulmn 5= " + cols[5] + " , Column 7=" + cols[7]);
```

The output should be

```
12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SnakeYAML:2.1:3,OverDue
12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,Overdue
12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:Apache Tomcat:9.0.70:1,Due in <= 90
12345:sdc-bh-registry-svc:Jettison - Json Stax implementation:1.5.3:1,Due in <=90
12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:Apache Tomcat:9.0.70:2,Due in >90
12345:sdc-posistion-svc:jackson-databind:2.14:1,OverDue
12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:jackson-databind:2.14:1,Due in <= 90
12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,Overdue
12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,OverDue
```

Comment: If you create a class containing 2 strings, you can replace `.map(list -> list.get(titleIndex))` with something which creates an instance of that class, i.e. `.map(list -> new MyClass(list.get(titleIndex), list.get(otherIndex)))`. The downstream methods would, of course, also have to change to support the object instead of a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the csv shared by you, it is acually `col8` and not `col7`.

Most of the work you have already done. Like you have fetched `col5`, you can fetch `col8` as well.

1. As you have done for `col5`, define variable to hold `col8` as well:

   ```
   String titleForCol8 = "col8";
   ```
2. Find the index for `col8`:

   ```
   int col8Idex = columns.indexOf(titleForCol8);
   ```
3. Append `col5` and `col8` in the result in the stream processing segment.

   ```
   .map(list -> list.get(titleIndex).concat(",").concat(list.get(col8Idex)))
   ```

Comment: It is working as expected. Thanks a lot